# Natural Deduction proof for $\forall x \neg A \implies \neg \exists xA$

Tags: logic

$\forall x \neg A \implies \neg \exists xA$
I won't ask you to solve this for me, but can you please give some guiding lines on how to approach a proof in NDFOL?
There are many tricks that the TA shows in class, that I could not dream of...

P.S. I managed to proof $\neg \exists xA \implies \forall x \neg A$ but could not get on from there.
Thanks!

---

After the proposed answer, let me see if I got this correct:

1. $\exists x A \implies \exists x A$ (<strike>axiom</strike> assumption)
2. $\exists x A \implies A$ (from 1)
3. $\exists x A, \forall x \neg A \implies \forall x \neg A$ (<strike>axiom</strike> assumption)
4. $\exists x A, \forall x \neg A \implies \neg A$ ($\forall$ extraction, from 3)
5. $\forall x \neg A \implies \neg \exists x A$ (from 2,4)

Am I correct?
I could not understand the justification going from (1) to (2)

Comment: If you want a *Natural Deduction* proof, you won't be invoking *Axioms*. There are no logical axioms in a natural deduction systems.

Comment: The "axiom" I'm referring to are of the form ${A}\cup\gamma \implies A$

Comment: **Prove** is the verb, **proof** is the noun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prove an implication, the general guideline for constructing formal proofs is: Assume the premise and the negation of the consequence, and derive a contradiction.

In your present case:

---

Assume $\exists x A(x)$. By Existential Instantiation, we have $A(t)$ for some (unspecified but fixed) $t$.

Assume $\forall x \neg A(x)$. By Universal Instantiation, we have $\neg A(t)$.

Now $A(t)$ and $\neg A(t)$ combine into a contradiction $\bot$.

We use Negation Introduction on the open assumption $\exists x A(x)$ to conclude $\neg \exists x A(x)$.

Finally, by Implication Introduction, we conclude the desired $\forall x \neg A(x) \implies \neg \exists x A(x)$ holds without any assumption.

Q.E.D.

---

*Addressing OP's efforts:*

As you see, there is a difference in our notations. I have parametrised $A$ as $A(x)$, while you haven't. However, this is *crucial* for the inference of $(2)$ from $(1)$. The expression $A(t)$ contains a $t$, which we can think of as an arbitrary "witness" of $\exists x A(x)$. It is *this witness* $t$ we apply Universal Instantiation / $\forall$ Extraction to: Since $\forall x \neg A(x)$, in particular $\neg A(t)$, where $t$ is the witness to $\exists x A(x)$.

This working with witnesses requires some practice, and even then one can sometimes mix things up. They are however crucial for the validity of the reasoning, so be sure to try and derive some more "trivialities" containing existential quantifiers!

A final remark (inspired by the comment by Peter Smith) is that in place of where you wrote "axiom", it's better to write one of "assumption" or "hypothesis", because these words have different meanings in mathematical lingo.

Comment: thanks, I've updated my original question to reflect your answer. I'm having some troubles to figure out some steps.

Comment: 1) Yes, I've corrected myself. We call them axioms but mean assumptions. 2) Can we just propose t=x as a witness? Thanks for your explanations, there is a lot of work to do.

Comment: Ad 2.: No, that'd be an abuse of notation very likely to solicit mistakes (and unless you're really careful, it's simply wrong). $x$ is a _bound_ variable; it does not fit the rôle of the variable $t$ that is a witness, because this new variable $t$ must be really _new_: it must not have occurred anywhere else in the proof. // You're welcome. I hope to have been of some help.

Answer (score 1):

Stated in a slightly different way from LF...

1. $\forall x \neg A(x)$  (Assume)
2. $A(y)$  (Assume)
3. $\neg A(y)$  (Universal Specification, line 1)
4. $A(y) \wedge \neg A(y)$ (Join, lines 2, 3)
5. $\neg\exists x A(x) $ (Conclusion, line 2)
6. $\forall x \neg A(x) \rightarrow \neg\exists x A(x)$ (Conclusion, line 1)